# jQuery: How to hook and identify drop-down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dhtml

I have a list of rows containing selects:

```html
<ul>
  {% for select in selects %}
    <li>
      <select id="select-{{ select.id }}">
        <option selected disabled>Select value...</option>
        {% for value in values %}
          <option value="{{ value.id }}">{{ value.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I want to have unified jQuery code like:

```js
$(something).onSelect(function(value) {
  // use this.id as select id;
  // use value as selected value;
  return false; // don't change selected item, leave it as 'Select value...'
}
```

Comment: Give the <select> a common class and use that as the selector.

Comment: I added template cycle inserting multiple rows containing select input element. Maybe this will clarify the question

Comment: I understand you are looping.  That doesn't change my suggestion.  There is no reason that the selector has to be complicated and handle for different ids.  It can just select by a common class.  Once you are in the event handler, you can get the id off of the element if you want, to know which one you are dealing with

Comment: @Taplar can you elaborate please your comment as an answer with code?

Comment: what is `onSelect` ? is it some library you are using ?

Comment: @Swati That is just an example of pseudo-jQuery-js-code I would like to have. I want to solve it using the last version of jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*`in your selector this selects all elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given substring and then simply use `attr('id'))` and `.val()` to get values from select-box .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("select[id*='select']").on("change", function(value) {
  console.log($(this).attr('id')) //get id
  console.log($(this).val()) //get value
  //some condition 
  //to set first value
  //$(this).val('Select value...') //or
  //$("#"+$(this).attr('id')).val('Select value...')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

  <li>
    <select id="select-1">
      <option selected disabled>Select value...</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select id="select-2">
      <option selected disabled>Select value...</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>

    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select id="select-3">
      <option selected disabled>Select value...</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>

    </select>
  </li>

</ul>
```